# Session value is getting blank on next page in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using php session codeiginater. But on next page session value are unset automatically.

I started the session inside constructor like  session_start();

```
function login() {

$data['url']=base_url();
    if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
        $data = array('user' => ($this->input->post('username')),
            'pass' => ($this->input->post('password')));
            $result = $this->home_model->validate_user_login($data);
            if (empty($result)) {
                $data['error'] = "Please enter valid username and password...!!";
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $data['error']);
                redirect(base_url() . $this->config->item('home_url'));
            } else {
                $_SESSION['login_data']=$result[0];
                redirect(base_url() . "campaign_list");
            }
    } else {
        $this->load->view('/main/header_login', $data);
        $this->load->view('/main/login', true);
        $this->load->view('/main/footer_login', true);
    }
}
```

When I print the session at the time of initialize that time values are print. but in next page when I am getting that value that time it become blank.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login_data']['user_group']) && $_SESSION['login_data']['user_group']!="") {
}else{ redirect(base_url()); }
```

I have tried to implement codeiginater session but that is also cause same result.

Same code is working on other system.

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a library for session in code igniter. You dont have start it this way.

Comment: I have also try  $this->load->library('session');  and $this->session->set_userdata('login_data', $result[0]); but that time also I am facing same issue.

Comment: You have to load the library for every controller or in the CI_Controller.

Comment: Yes. I have load the library in every controller still it is not working.

Comment: bad practice to use php session in codeigniter framework, try to use CI session library by loading in autoload.php file.

Comment: i am facing same problem i am using only codeigniter session and also load library from autoload have you any solution ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **session library** i autoload.

In `config/autoload.php`

Change This Line

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array();
```

TO This LINE

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing between the native PHP SESSION and the Codeigniter session library.

```
$_SESSION['var'] // this is the native PHP Session

$this->session->userdata(); // this is the CI library
```

It seems that you are setting the variables on one and trying to get it on the other, so pick one method and stick with it. for example if you use the CI library, add it to the autoload and then you can

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('var'=>'value')); // set the session variable

$this->session->userdata('var'); // get the session variable
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same problem.
Now I find a solution. 
when I using tags setting in pagination configuration then I have problem.
these are config tags.

```
$config ['full_tag_open'] = '<nav><ul class="pagination">';
    $config ['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></nav>';
    $config ['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="arrow">';
    $config ['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config ['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config ['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
    $config ['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="arrow">';
    $config ['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config ['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config ['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="arrow">';
    $config ['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config ['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config ['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config ['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config ['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config ['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="arrow">';
    $config ['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config ['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

You remove this from pagination config. 
Then I hope problem will be solved.